# S gate vs P gate?

Tags: quantum-gate

The paper [A Fully Fault-Tolerant Representation of Quantum Circuits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.03962.pdf) uses the $P$ gate which is given as:
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & i\\\end{bmatrix}.$$

Nielsen and Chuang Quantum Computation and  Information 10th edition uses the $S$ gate which is also given as:
$$S = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & i\\\end{bmatrix}.$$

Why does the same gate has different names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoting phase gate by $P$ probably comes from its name *Phase*

Phase gate is usually denoted by $S$ as you can see from your Nielsen and Chuang book example. Moreoer, symbol $S$ is used also on IBM Q.

To sum up, it is a matter of a paper's author decission. As I remember, I have seen phase gate denoted by $S$ only.